# Change datatypes to be identical to a 2nd database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-schema, sql-server-2016

I have two identical SQL Server databases. (SQL Server 2016 Developer edition) and one of them has incorrect data types (`Ntext` etc.), while the second database has correct data types (`nvarchar(n)` etc.).

I want to update database #1 and change all datatype to the corresponding datatypes used in database #2.

Column and table names are the same but data is different.

Comment: And what's your problem?

Comment: This will be opinion based, you need to perform some utility which will get the column data type and update to database 1, also you might need to take a backup of data then truncate it and then change data.

Comment: On method is with the schema compare feature of SSDT (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt). This will identify differences, allowing changes to be selectively applied either interactively or by generating a T-SQL script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure but you can probably join the information schema tables from both databases and check for differences:

```
SELECT d1.TABLE_NAME, d1.COLUMN_NAME
     , d1.DATA_TYPE, d2.DATA_TYPE
     , d1.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, d2.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM database2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS d2
LEFT JOIN database1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS d1 ON
          d2.TABLE_NAME = d1.TABLE_NAME AND
          d2.COLUMN_NAME = d1.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE d2.TABLE_NAME IS NULL
OR d1.DATA_TYPE <> d2.DATA_TYPE
OR d1.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH <> d2.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
```

You could then inspect the results and generate the alter table queries.